# Jquery canvas touch count

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, canvas

Can someone help me with a script I'm working with.
http://jsfiddle.net/InVAMPED/XsG4e/4/

What I'm trying to achieve is placing a image where the user touches(ipad).
There will be say 5 images that will each get attached once only.

So first touch places img1, second touch imag2 etc untill all the images have been placed.
Problem with my fsfiddle example is that when on ipad it doesnt count the first touch so you place the first image twice. it does duplicate the image on the second time just moves it to the second touches coordinates, then move on to 2, 3, 4, 5 as it should.

any advice? or help to do this a better way?

thanks

Comment: Sorry but can anyone else help? adding the canvas to the HTML does not seem to solve the problem of the first image not sticking to the first touch position. It works great on desktop but not on ipad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified ur code. Moved canvas to HTML part. It works for me on iphone.

Comment: Probably better practice to fork the fiddle and link to the updated version from your answer. Also, would be more helpful if you posted details of the solution on this page as the fiddle may not survive.

Comment: My idea when u created canvas on fly its not immidiatelly active. So when its rendered from begginigng it works better. Move canvas to static HTML and test. For my iphone it works. Sorry for disturbing ur code. Never used this online editor before.

Comment: It's not my code or question, just offering you some tips on how to improve your answer. Have a look at the fork button on jsfiddle which will allow you to create a new fiddle based on the original. That way you don't disturb the original which may be useful to other users.